# Problems with html tags that have class in Swift, using .replacingOccurences()

Tags: html, ios, swift, webview, textview

I am trying to implement html inside of a UITextView, but I can't manage to render paragraphs or any other tags from HTML that have their own classes, first line where its just p, without class, works, but other one with class doesn't. Can someone find out where am I wrong?

Thanks in advance.

```
.replacingOccurrences(of: "<p", with: "<p style=\"font-family:Trenda-Regular;font-size:14px;\"")
.replacingOccurrences(of: "<p class=\"semi-bold\" ", with: "<p style=\"font-family:Trenda-Semibold;font-size:14px;\"")
```

**EDIT**

```
 let textView: UITextView = {
    let textView = UITextView()
    textView.isEditable = false
    
    let htmlText = 
    """
       <html>    
        <head>    
         <title>Terms of Use</title>    
       </head> 
        <body>   
          <p class="semi-bold">You shall not:</p>
       </body>
      </html>
   """
    textView.attributedText = html.htmlToAttributedString
    textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return textView
}()


extension String {

var localized: String {
    return NSLocalizedString(self, tableName: nil, bundle: Bundle.main, value: "", comment: "")
}

var htmlToAttributedString: NSAttributedString? {
    
    let text = self.replacingOccurrences(of: "<h3", with: "<h3 style=\"font-family:Trenda-Semibold;font-size:32px;\"")
        .replacingOccurrences(of: "<h4", with: "<h4 style=\"font-family:Trenda-Regular;font-size:24px;\"")
        .replacingOccurrences(of: "<h5", with: "<h5 style=\"font-family:Trenda-Regular;font-size:20px;\"")
        .replacingOccurrences(of: "<p", with: "<p style=\"font-family:Trenda-Regular;font-size:14px;\"")
        .replacingOccurrences(of: "<p class=\"semi-bold\" ", with: "<p style=\"font-family:Trenda-Semibold;font-size:14px;\"")
        .replacingOccurrences(of: "<strong", with: "<strong style=\"font-family:Trenda-Regular;font-size:14px;\"")
        .replacingOccurrences(of: "<li", with: "<li style=\"font-family:Trenda-Regular;font-size:14px;\"")
        .replacingOccurrences(of: "</ul>", with: "</ul></br>")
    
    guard let data = text.data(using: .utf8) else { return nil }
    do {
        return try NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, .characterEncoding:String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil)
    } catch {
        return nil
    }
}

var htmlToString: String {
    return htmlToAttributedString?.string ?? ""
}
```

}

Comment: `NSAttributedString` won't do the job? Wha's the code after that? How do you use the resulting `String`?

Comment: sorry, my question wasn't written very good. I edited my question, please take a look. @Larme

Comment: Side note, you replace first `<p` with p1 and then `"<p class=\"semi-bold\"` with p2, but if there was before a `"<p class=\"semi-bold\"`, it'd be replace by p1, not p2. Reverse the order